# Can a dwarf fruit tree grow well with just morning sun?

Tags: fruit-trees, sunlight, growth, apples

I ordered a dwarf "Garden Prince" almond tree and a dwarf "Fuji" apple tree and I want to keep them in a container on my balcony. The balcony gets great sun in the morning, especially in the summer. I live in zone 7B and we get really hot and humid summers here.

However, I was wondering if that'll be enough sun for them to produce any fruit.  I've read some conflicting things online where someone said these trees could grow okay in part sun.

If the harvest is smaller, that should be okay since it's just for my husband and I.

Answer (score 5):

I see some problems here:
Fuji apple trees are not self fertile so you would need two late blooming apple trees to get any fruit set
Anything less than full sun will reduce the amount of flower and fruit set.  How your plants will do could vary depending on such hard to measure things as amount of reflected light, if there are drying winds to stress the plant and so on
Even a dwarf apple tree will need some well informed pruning to keep the amount of top weight within manageable proportions.
Likely you would want to do some thinning after fruit set to get fewer but larger apples.  Some research on this will show you how easy this can be.

The almond tree is self fertile but normally grows 10 to 12 feet, but can be controlled to grow only 8 feet.  Even in a pot on a balcony a mature height of 6' to 8' with annual pruning is not out of the question.
Again, reduced sun equates to reduced yield.
For both plants they require chill hours to set dormancy.
  As much as they need a few hundred hours of temperatures below 15 degree Fahrenheit their root systems cannot get too cold.  Depending on your location you may wish to buy some Styrofoam SM or similar insulation and make a little box around the pot to assist in the wintering over.

It is likely they will grow and set fruit and nuts at a reduced yield and with the proviso a more maintenance than for in ground plants.  Whether they will grow "well" is too hard to tell

Comment: I have a Gala apple tree as well, so my Fuji has a mate.